# Linux: writing status often to a small file, where?

Tags: linux, ramdisk

I want this program of mine to expose its status for others to read. The first thing that comes to my mind is to write this to a file, but the flow of my program makes it convenient to update this status several times a second which makes it stupid to write it to disk every time.

Is there for example a way of storing this file in memory only, available on the file system without manually mounting a ramdisk somewhere?

My program is written in Python, those reading its status could be anything.

Comment: This almost seems like it might belong on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It won't be physically written to the disk very often, because it is staying in filesystem cache. Just write a file several times per second. Trust the kernel for caching and sync-ing to disk (which you could force with `sync()` or `fsync()`...)

Answer (score 4):

Why not have your program open a [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) or [Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) Socket, and build some kind of interface to allow systems to connect and request the status as needed?

Answer (score 1):

Anything in /dev/shm, it's in ram so it's fast, and no syncing issues.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a shared memory segment and opening that with your programs?  One thing, all people sharing the shared memory segment MUST be on the same system.